# Using Visual Studio with Bootstrap and Umbraco

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, umbraco7

I need some assistance setting up a solution in Visual Studio which uses Umbraco.

I'm planning on developing with the Umbraco CMS platform in Visual Studio 2013, using C# and Bootstrap.  Source control will be done with Team Foundation Server.

I understand that I need to create an empty ASP.NET MVC Application, then create a C# Class, then use NuGet to install Umbraco on my development server.  Do I need to do anything else to set up my environment?

And where exactly does Bootstrap fit into this?

Answer (score 2):

First of all - Umbraco it is a Content Management System. It provides you an a back-office for managing content of your system.

Umbraco also have a project template which you can download inside visual studio. This project contains all needed structure and packages in it.

Here are couple of useful links:

[**Umbraco Template Project**](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/8d0ca3f2-c626-4485-8794-0922ea67e949)

[**Article called NuGet Packages and Visual Studio Templates**](http://umbraco.com/follow-us/blog-archive/2012/2/28/nuget-packages-and-visual-studio-templates)

So now, when you have Umbraco installed and you have your back-office - you need to display your content somehow for end users. Here is a place where you can use Bootstrap to apply styling for your content.

Comment: Im aware of what Umbraco is and how it works, what I want to use is Visual Studio 2013 and use MVC4 to develop the content for this using Bootstrap for responsiveness.   That in itself isn't a problem but I'm unaware of how to develop content in Visual Studio and how it integrates with Umbraco without using a theme or template.  Reading what your saying, is that I develop the views in Visual Studio, then manage the content in Umbraco.  This in itself is fine, but how do you access the views from Umbraco?

Comment: But what for you need MVC4? You need only Views form MVC, which is basically called Templates in Umbraco. You can use Bootstrap on this templates as well as any other frontend framework.

Comment: For this you need to create a project form Umbraco Template in VS. That you will have Project with Views folder and you will have all references to Umbraco Components on the views.

Comment: I don't want to use a template.  Developing a template from what I understand is a large pain in the backside and not very open in terms of customisability site wide.  I want to use Visual studio which has a far better development suite than the web based interface in Umbraco.  EDIT.  Theres an umbrage template for VS?

Comment: Sir, but Umbraco Templates are simply .cshtml views. You can develop them in Visual Studio as well. In Umbraco you need just create them. (You can't create them from Visual studio because they are assigned to Umbraco Document Types)

Comment: Ok looked at the Umbraco Templates in Visual Studio.  Got knows why I didn't look there before or google it..  Plainly obvious answer..  Ok, so do I even need to create an ASP.NET application before I install Umbraco?  Or can I just go ahead and develop a View from the Template downloadable from VS, insert it into the Umbraco Installation and manage content?

Comment: You can create VS project directly in folder where you have your Umbraco website installed, and you don't even need to move your views. You will have them in both Umbraco and VS Project.

Comment: ok superb to sum up.  Install Umbraco after you create an empty ASP.NET MVC project, then use the Umbraco template, insert the Bootstrap Files as they need to, link normally into the project, and away you go and add content with the back-office after you create your page?

Comment: You shoul create not MVC project, but Umbraco project. See links in my answer.

Comment: As I understand you need to create an Empty ASP.NET Project in order to Install Umbraco.  So I take it you don't need to go ahead and create and MVC files, just install Umbraco using NuGet?

Comment: That is on of the options.

Comment: Ok excellent stuff and thanks.  the article that is on the Umbraco website is from 2012 and covers Umbraco 5.. How relevant is it to Umbraco 7 exactly?  And are there any other recommended solutions?  Also, My approach to MVC is just that.  Folders called Model, View Controller.  Am I under the understanding and opinion that Umbraco differs from this File Structure but does adopt MVC and MVVM?  Ta

Answer (score -3):

I just started testing Umbraco recently. I installed using the Web Platform Installer which setup Umbraco using WebMatrix. From there, WebMatrix has an option to open the web app in a Visual Studio solution.

Most of the time I still use the Umbraco back end to edit templates and partial views/macros, but for more complicated ones I use the VS solution to edit the cshtml files directly. The added value of Intellisense is quite helpful, plus you can attach to IIS Express and debug the macros.

As for Bootstrap, I've referenced all necessary files in a master template from which all other templates inherit. Initially I used the free Umbraco Bootstrap template from Bind Tuning, but didn't see how it was any better than just installing the bootstrap files manually, or even referencing the CDN.

I did try the NuGet package, and if memory serves, there is an issue with source files not available if you choose the local db option (which I did since I was just evaluating Umbraco).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I explained an easy way to setup a solution in Visual Studio to work with Umbraco - which addresses the request for assistance in the Op's first sentence.